# Display an Openstreetmap relation on an Android phone?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Is there an Android App out there, that can display Openstreetmap relation, like https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/31617

Answer (score 0):

Relation [31617](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/31617) is a bicycle route (displaying it on the OSM website will fail due to the relation's size but downloading the [raw data](https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/31617/full) works).

Yes, there are apps for Android that are able to display such routes, for example OsmAnd. But I'm not sure if this really answers your question. If not then please describe your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

Need to [download a relation as a .gpx file](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/23679/how-to-export-a-route-relation-as-gpx-or-kml) on your phone first. Then open the file with a maps application, such as OsmAnd.